# How can I analyze mindump?

Tags: windbg

Can somebody walk through the command it will take to find third party driver probably as a culprit for BSOD in attached minidump.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqhhsryB84SOjPNG54-xPUQQ5SoouQ

I already run `analyze -v` which did not provide any clues to any third party drivers, only microsoft ones.

Comment: Typically, the first step would be to run `!analyze -v` after loading the minidump.

Comment: I did and it did not provide any info

Comment: @GSA: then, why didn't you include that information in the question? It also seems that the title is wrong then. You know how to analyze it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Updated question mentioning that basic triage was already done.

Comment: @magicandre1981 would you mind telling me steps you took to find this information

Comment: I looked in the dump for strings with PDE.dll extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732613/why-slack-is-causing-windows-10-bsod#comment74526653_43732613

Comment: Add this as answer to this question so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) by running `!analyze -v` doesn't show enough details:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff8032ae9ada2, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffff8c001ea8eda0, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------

00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiSystemServiceHandler
03 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
04 nt!RtlDispatchException
05 nt!KiDispatchException
06 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
07 nt!KiGeneralProtectionFault
08 nt!ObDereferenceSecurityDescriptor
09 nt!SeDefaultObjectMethod
0a nt!ObpRemoveObjectRoutine
0b nt!ObfDereferenceObjectWithTag
0c nt!ObCloseHandleTableEntry
0d nt!NtClose
0e nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
0f 0x0
```

So you get a  00000000c0000005 - access denied error while closing a handle. Next I used PDE.dll from Andrew Richards and dumped all data with `!pde.dpx` and here I see a McAfee DLL:

```
0xffff8c001ea8ee08 : 0xfffff8032acd634b : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x34b
0xffff8c001ea8ee98 : 0xfffff8032ae9ada2 : nt!ObDereferenceSecurityDescriptor+0x12
Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mfehidk.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for mfehidk.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for mfehidk.sys
0xffff8c001ea8f058 : 0xfffff8032aafdc5a : nt!ExpReleaseResourceForThreadLite+0x13a
0xffff8c001ea8f068 : 0xfffff8032aafdac4 : nt!ExAcquireResourceSharedLite+0x394
0xffff8c001ea8f0c8 : 0xfffff8032acd634b : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x34b
0xffff8c001ea8f0e8 : 0xfffff8032aab5420 : nt!MiFlushTbList+0x2f0
0xffff8c001ea8f100 : 0xfffff8032adc1100 : nt!NonPagedPoolDescriptor
0xffff8c001ea8f228 : 0xfffff8032ab35ddc : nt!RtlGetExtendedContextLength+0x34
0xffff8c001ea8f248 : 0xfffff8032ae81619 : nt!ObpCallPreOperationCallbacks+0x269
0xffff8c001ea8f2f8 : 0xfffff8032ab51ecb : nt!MiFlushHyperSpace+0x8b
0xffff8c001ea8f348 : 0xfffff8032ac4ae2d : nt!HvlpFastFlushAddressSpaceTb+0x59
0xffff8c001ea8f3b8 : 0xfffff8032ac4abde : nt!HvlFlushAddressSpaceTb+0x5e
0xffff8c001ea8f438 : 0xfffff8032abe7a02 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0xc2
0xffff8c001ea8f538 : 0xfffff8032adac040 : nt!MiSystemPartition
0xffff8c001ea8f588 : 0xfffff8032ae9ada2 : nt!ObDereferenceSecurityDescriptor+0x12
0xffff8c001ea8f618 : 0xfffff8032abe5cbd : nt!KiGeneralProtectionFault+0xfd
0xffff8c001ea8f620 : 0xfffff8800001f2f8 :  Trap @ ffff8c001ea8f620
0xffff8c001ea8f628 : 0xfffff8032aaead13 : nt!MiDeleteVirtualAddresses+0xf63
0xffff8c001ea8f6f8 : 0xfffff8032aad3470 : nt!MiGetVadWakeList+0x120
0xffff8c001ea8f718 : 0xfffff8032acd634b : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x34b
0xffff8c001ea8f738 : 0xfffff8032adac040 : nt!MiSystemPartition
0xffff8c001ea8f748 : 0xfffff8032aeaa349 : nt!MiRemoveVadCharges+0x219
0xffff8c001ea8f788 : 0xfffff8032ae9ada2 : nt!ObDereferenceSecurityDescriptor+0x12
0xffff8c001ea8f7b8 : 0xfffff8032aad3307 : nt!MiFinishVadDeletion+0x3d7
0xffff8c001ea8f7c8 : 0xfffff8032acd634b : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x34b
0xffff8c001ea8f7e8 : 0xfffff8032ae9a948 : nt!SeDefaultObjectMethod+0xa8
0xffff8c001ea8f7f8 : 0xfffff8032aea8f4a : nt!MiRemoveSharedCommitNode+0x29a
0xffff8c001ea8f828 : 0xfffff8032af268c9 : nt!ObpLookupDirectoryUsingHash+0x95
0xffff8c001ea8f838 : 0xfffff8032ae96337 : nt!ObpRemoveObjectRoutine+0xc7
0xffff8c001ea8f898 : 0xfffff8032ab00326 : nt!ObfDereferenceObjectWithTag+0xc6
0xffff8c001ea8f8d8 : 0xfffff8032aeb135b : nt!ObCloseHandleTableEntry+0x28b
0xffff8c001ea8fa18 : 0xfffff8032aefb5db : nt!NtClose+0xcb

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\mfehidk.sys
Image name: mfehidk.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Wed Nov 30 22:56:01 2016
```

Remove the McAfee software if no update is available.